# Upload a file in Azure Blob Storage using React

Tags: reactjs, azure, file-upload, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a requirement where I need to upload a .txt file to Azure Blob storage from my React Application. I have created a file upload button in React , when triggered would connect to my Azure Blob storage account and upload the file there. I have seen many examples on how to do this but I am not clear on how to connect my Azure Blob storage account from my React app. All the examples I see are using Node and .ts notations. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this using React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Link where you have step-by-step procedure to upload files to blob storage using React

[Upload to Azure Blob Storage with React | by Stuart Tottle | Medium](https://stuarttottle.medium.com/upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-react-34f37805fdfc)

Below is the code which you can download
[stottle-uk/stottle-react-blob-storage (github.com)](https://github.com/stottle-uk/stottle-react-blob-storage)

Below is the Solution for the example code
[StottleReactBlobStorage (stottle-blob-storage-react.azurewebsites.net)](https://stottle-blob-storage-react.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Thanks I was able to achieve this using the above link and just for your reference the sample from https://github.com/shubhamagarwal/Blob-Storage also works.